# Retrieve RGB image from 1-dim array containing RGB image data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I pass a C array containing RGB image data to a function in Python to further process the image. 
How can I retrieve this image and plot it as well in Python?

the C array named **c_data** that contains RGB image data was created by

```
for(k = 0; k < c; ++k){
    for(j = 0; j < h; ++j){
        for(i = 0; i < w; ++i){
            int dst_index = i + w*j + w*h*k;
            int src_index = k + c*i + c*w*j;
            c_data[dst_index] = (float)stb_im[src_index]/255.;
        }
    }
}
```

the C array is converted into a numpy array and is passed to the Python function with the following header via the parameter named **im_data**

```
def read_img_from_c(im_data, im_h, im_w):

print(im_h) // 480
print(im_w) // 640
print(im_data.shape) // (921600,) --> (480*640*3)
```

I tried to simply reshape the numpy array using

```
data = im_data.reshape((im_h, im_w, 3))
```

and create a PIL image object using

```
img = PIL.Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
```

, but when I run the following command

```
img.show()
```

I got the following rather than the original image.

[image]

Update: I follow the suggestion by multiplying those normalized pixel values by 255.0, cast the numpy array to type int and plot:

```
im_data = (im_data*255.0).astype(np.uint8)
im_data = im_data.reshape((im_h, im_w, 3))
img = Image.fromarray(im_data, 'RGB')
img.show()
```

and I got the image with repeated patterns instead of a single big RGB 
image:

[image: The original image was from the MOT16-02 sequence of the MOTChallenge Benchmark dataset]

Comment: According to documentation https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes `RGB` mode is 3x8-bit pixel, I suggest creating 1-d Array, which each element will be array made of RGB values [R , G, B] from one pixel, If this does not work you can also try to make 1-d Array with 3 color channels in it

Comment: Kind of looks like at some point that height and width got mixed. Try swap the order and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try multiplying `data` by `255` again and rounding it to int. I guess the values in RGB tuple should be from range `0-255`, not `0-1`.

Answer (score 1):

After spent a day for recovering this image, I have found a solution.

I believe that the flatten version of my normalized image pixels were stored in the one-dimensional array named `im_data` that looks like this

> [ r1 g1 b1 r2 g2 b2 ... rN gN bN]

, where subscript `N` is the number of pixels.

So, the first step I multiply each pixel with `255.0` to get pixel values between `0-255`:

```
import numpy as np
im_data = (im_data*255.0).astype(np.uint8)
```

and rather than reshaping the array using a shape of `(im_h, im_w, 3)`, I reshape it using a shape of `(3, im_h, im_w)` so:

```
im_data = im.reshape((3, im_h, im_w))
```

Finally, I transpose the result numpy array to get a correct image shape, which is `(im_h, im_w, 3)`, so:

```
im_data = np.transpose(im, (1, 2, 0))
```

Finally,

```
img = Image.fromarray(im_data, 'RGB')
img.show()
```

and boom:
[image]
(the image is one of the MOTChallenge benchmark dataset https://motchallenge.net/)

To be honest, I am not totally sure about how all these works out. I just mess around with array operations.